# What instrument in a drum kit is played on the second and fourth beat of a song during a verse or pre-chorus?

Tags: rhythm, drums, pop-music, acapella, beatbox

I've tried to locate this particular sound in a drum kit, but I can't figure out what it's called. It's equivalent to hitting your drumsticks together on every second and fourth beat of a song during the verse or pre-chorus. Usually the kick bass is played on the first and third beats. But the clicking sound usually transitions into a full on snare in the chorus of the song. Here's an example of this.

As you'll notice, towards the pre-chorus of this song, even though it was probably done using beatboxing, the clicking is still there, on the second and fourth beats of the piece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a sidestick.
It's made by resting the rear end of the sick on one edge of the skin & tapping the rim on the far side.
Not to be confused with a rim-shot, which is a full down-stroke, hitting both skin & rim simultaneously.

I'd point you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rimshot except for the fact I disagree with half of what it says [either that or the UK & US use these terms differently].

Answer (score 3):

That is (or is supposed to imitate) a "rim click", or "cross-stick" or "side-stick".
It is played by holding the tip of the stick on the drum head, with your (usually left) hand on the stick used to both play the other end against the rim and mute the head to avoid resonance and obtaining a dry sound, similar to that of a pair of *claves*.